# SWT modal dialog not modal

Tags: java, dialog, swt, modal-dialog

According to another discussion here, I try to open a modal view like so:

```
public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

    final Shell dialogShell = new Shell(ApplicationRunner.getApp()
            .getShell().getDisplay(), SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL | SWT.SHEET);

    dialogShell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Button closeButton = new Button(dialogShell, SWT.PUSH);
    closeButton.setText("Close");
    closeButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            dialogShell.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    dialogShell.setDefaultButton(closeButton);
    dialogShell.addDisposeListener(new DisposeListener() {

        public void widgetDisposed(DisposeEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Modal dialog closed");
        }
    });
    dialogShell.pack();
    dialogShell.open();
}
```

It opens the desired window, but it's not modal. I can access the main shell and open another instance of the same modal dialog. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanx, Marcus

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would highly recommend creating your own JFace Dialog by extending `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog` rather than creating your own shell with buttons.
[Here](http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/eclipseplugins/032142672X/ch11lev1sec1.html) is a really good tutorial on this.

Within the contructor you can call `setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.OK | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);` which will make this dialog completely modal, if you call the constructor with your main shell as the parameter. Like this:

```
public CheckboxDialog(Shell parentShell) {
    super(parentShell);
    setShellStyle(SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.OK | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    setBlockOnOpen(true);
}
```

where `parentShell` is the main shell of your GUI.

Comment: thanx to you, again 8) seems like, there are not many programmers around, dealing with stw/jface (anymore). Did I miss a new and flashy possibility to do desktop applications?

Comment: @MarcusToepper Itoo  was surprised, that there aren't many SWT developers around. Seems they are all dealing with Swing/AWT. I've worked with both and I really prefer SWT...

Comment: Considering the age of both, one would think, there might be any new APIs around anyway, but these days, everything seems to evolve around web solutions only. Like JavaFX for applications or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today, when creating a pop-up window defined in a separate class.

I was using something like `popup_shell = new Shell(Display.getCurrent(), SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL | SWT.DIALOG_TRIM)` inside the constructor for the new window.

If instead I pass in the shell from the parent window, like so:

```
public PopupWindow(Shell main_shell)
{
    popup_shell = new Shell(main_shell, SWT.PRIMARY_MODAL | SWT.DIALOG_TRIM);
}
```

then it works properly.

My guess is that both `ApplicationRunner.getApp().getShell().getDisplay()` and `Display.getCurrent()` result in a completely new shell, unconnected to the parent window, so primary_modal has no effect.